# Preventing directory listing by redirecting?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to use `.htaccess` to prevent directory listing.
I've got pages within */location/* but I don't have an index file. So I want to redirect to */location/about.php* for example.

Is there a way to do this, without creating an *index.html* and redirecting requests to that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're asking for a file in place of 'index.html', see "[DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)" to tell it what files to use in place of 'index.html':

```
DirectoryIndex about.php index.html
Options –Indexes
```

... if you're trying to redirect all directories to a single page, then I'd cheat and do the following, which will mostly do what you're asking for:

```
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions +SuppressHTMLPreamble
IndexIgnore *
HeaderName /includes/header.html
ReadmeName /includes/readme.html
```

... and set /includes/header.html with whatever message you want (or containing a meta-redirect), and /includes/readme.html to be blank.

Comment: I used the first example. However including Options -Indexes resulted in a internal server error. So I just used DirectoryIndex to replace the default .html then reflected this in each directory nessecary. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an older thread but I just had to implement something similar and did it the following way:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /location/about.php
```

Basically, `Options -Indexes` prevents directory listing and `ErrorDocument 403` rewrites the default 403 message.

Comment: Be aware that this might cause some unintended side effects -- 403 responses will not be indexed by many (most?) search engines

Comment: And 403 is "access forbidden" - did you want perhaps 404?

Answer (score 1):

Changing `DirectoryIndex` and `Options` works, but using mod_alias means that you don't have to change it back in nested directories.

```
Redirect 303 /location/ /location/about.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct link to what you need:

http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml

If you need something more advanced to handle parameters or need to remap old URLs to new ones, you can use URL rewriting:

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Prevent directory listing (or return an empty directory listing):

http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/prevent-directory-listing.html

Comment: Im not wanting to redirect a page, im wanting to redirect a directory to a page. However if I redirect a whole directory, every page within that directory will point to the redirected page. Or so I am to belive.