# Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have used my `.htaccess` file to

1. Provide a 404 page
2. Turn off directory scanning.

Here is the relevant portion of the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /Page-Not-Found.html
```

The 404 part works. [Test](http://www.chihuahuarescuevictoria.org/something/nosuchpage).

However, going to a directory [that actually exists](http://www.chihuahuarescuevictoria.org/chihuahuaStories/2014/) (directory scanning) gives back this:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /chihuahuaStories/2014/ on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: You turned off directory listing so `Forbidden` is expected. What is your expected behavior?

Comment: I thought it should show the 404 page based on the error message itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these directives at top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /Page-Not-Found.html
ErrorDocument 403 /Page-Not-Found.html
```

Comment: Yes amazing coincidence. But that also means your Apache config had some other `ErrorDocument 403 ...` that got correctly overwritten with this .htaccess.

Comment: Is there a way that servers provide defaults for this? My .htaccess file has only 7 lines..

Comment: Yes there might be some defaults there but clearly those wrong defaults were causing additional 404

Answer (score 2):

OK, thanks to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13570995/257233), I have found the solution, which is to provide the following:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /Page-Not-Found.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on my WordPress website after migrating to a new server.

> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
> use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I did not get the 404 for the admin area or the home page. Only got the error on pages and post. I fixed this error by accident. In the admin area, I clicked on the settings/permalink to check if the permalinks were matching my old WordPress website settings and they did. So, I clicked the update button. When I clicked the update button that fixed the problem.

I think what happen is when I clicked the update button on the permalink page it updated the .htaccess file.