# I want to put a index.php in every sub directory. Is this a good/bad programming practice?

Tags: php, web, coding-style, web-deployment, easyphp

I **don't** want the user to see the sub directory structures. So I am thinking of redirecting the user to the homepage whenever they try to access that.

Comment: You can prevent users from accessing empty directories in web server configuration.

Comment: Yes you can do this. But the problem is when ever you create a directory you need to put index.php. Better approach would be using `htaccess` to prevent directory listing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229127/preventing-directory-listing-by-redirecting

Comment: htaccess definitely is an alternative, but you may want to read this: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/ (in short, using htaccess isn't free either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just put .htaccess file with `Options -Indexes` in it in root directory.

[How do I disable directory browsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing)