# Redirect if there is no index file found

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, localhost

Is there a way in my localhost (Laragon) to change the page that you see when there is no index from this
[image: ugly]

to this
[image: nice]
I have made this page myself but now I want make all the files like this, this is just a simple index.php file but I don't want to manually add this file when there is no index file

Which file do I have to make or edit to make this?

Comment: You mean [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1229729/3578036)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing directory listing by redirecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229127/preventing-directory-listing-by-redirecting)

Comment: Are you really just trying to style the directory listing?

Comment: Yes style the directory listing

Answer (score 0):

Laragon web server is **Apache**, so you'll need to configure Apache to use a custom "DirectoryIndex".

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#DirectoryIndex.